# Unable to connect to SQL Server database (error 25) in PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I've tried to connect to a SQL Server database (to get data) via DirectQuery and got an Error 25:

> Connection String is not valid.

But when I tried to import data from that server, it was successful and I was able to visualize it. However working with a large set of data (**700k-1mln rows** and 10+ columns) it would be more logical to connect via DirectQuery. Is there anything you can suggest?

Has anyone experienced this issue before and if yes, how did you resolve it?

Edit: I have corrected typo with row count, sorry my bad. Regarding your comments, DQ is a must have requirement.

[image: Error 25]

Comment: It is clearly showing the underlying connection either server name, user id, or password is incorrect or do not have permission to run the query in that database.

Comment: Check the server name you entered. It must be mistyped. Also "couple hundreds of rows and 10+ columns" is not a valid reason to go to DQ. Power BI can handle way more.

Comment: Just don't use Direct Query, unless your data exceeds billion records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: **Solution: for DQ in Powerbi, you should put "," instead of ":" in front of a port as a server . e.g. servername,port

But for import, semicolon works fine.**

References: [Solution from PowerBI community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Schedule-Refresh-doesn-t-work-because-of-port-issues/m-p/537214#M20242)